# Toyota camry 2005 steering wheel on Toyota camry 2002?

Tags: steering-wheel, head-unit

I have installed a new head unit in my Toyota camry 2002. The head unit is SWC compatible. I was hoping to take advantage of that feature. The steering wheel I have now only has 2 buttons on the wheel. After doing some research I discover the steering wheel for a Toyota camry 2005 has several additional buttons such as volume control.

It is possible to use a Toyota camry 2005 steering wheel on a Toyota camry 2002? Would the buttons on the steering wheel be able to register or send commands?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the new head unit a stock Toyota unit? If not, you'll need an adapter which can receive the signal from the steering wheel controls in order to use it. Plus, I'm unsure how the steering wheel controls are powered ... you'd need to figure it out as well. You'll also want to be careful of the air bag ... ugly. Doubly make sure it's not a Takata one.